# Is it possible to update my current iOS app from App Store?

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store, xcode6.1

When I navigate on my app on device, I have some restrictions for some screen and what I have to do is to access App Store directly from my app when I select Ok button from the popup that restricted that page. Is it possible to create a way which can access directly App Store and to make update for my current app?

Comment: What do you mean by restrictions for some screen? Is your app already registered on App Store?

Comment: No, my app is not on App Store yet. One of restriction is when I want to make a payment and payment view is restricted by me, and I don't show payment view from delegate, but I show that pop-up which if is selected with OK, I have to go directly in App Store to make update.

Comment: So let me get this right. 1) I download your app. 2) I navigate in your app to this page and select "OK" on the popup. 3) I am taken back to the app store where I just downloaded your app from. Is this correct?

Comment: If the above is correct, then that is a bad user journey if I have just downloaded the app I don't want to be taken back to be told I have to do an update, if I download it I expect to get the latest (That is actually how the app store works anyway by giving the latest version). You have either not explained yourself correctly OR you don't understand how things are meant to work in the app store (I get the feeling you don't understand). So please can you clarify everything you want

Comment: What you said in the first comment is what I have to do, yes, you understood, BUT I find a way to resolve this problem and I just tested it and it works.

Comment: What I did was to create a simple way to app store, just like here: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lumosity-mobile/id577232024?mt=8"]]]; This link contains a test app and what i'll do, i'll change the parameters with my parameters. So thanks for being interested

Comment: Well it seems pointless. If I have already downloaded the app I would expect to have the latest one through either the fact I have just downloaded it OR the App store has pushed the update to me. So making the user go back to the app store is bad. Also you can't have multiple versions of the app on the app store when you submit and update it will override the old version on the app store which would be the standard update the user would get anyway. Your design is flawed, bad and extremely bad for the user and most of all pointless. I don;t think you filly understand how the app store works

Comment: This app is a big app with a lot of screens and if you want to make "the next" step you are blocked by alert view. You have this pop up in two situations and one of this is if you want to sign your contract. You can make an idea about this app if you watch this video: http://vimeo.com/65868004. It's not such a pointless thing! @Popeye

Comment: Well the way you want to do it isn't possible. You can't have a build on the App store the user downloads then have another separate one for updating it. What you will need to do is have all the screens in the app and request an update from your own private server which it will then download all the additional content. Please be aware though that this method of updating your app could have the chance of getting rejected in the Apple Review process. But the way you want to do it is definitely not possible at all so I'd forget about it there is just no way it can be done